# how to merge all js files into one bundle webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, bundle

How to merge all js files into one? With minify in webpack 1.* ?

Here is my part of webpack config

```
entry: {
    bundle: "./src/index.tsx",
    styles: './static/scss/main.scss',

    main : [
        './static/js/jquery.js',
        './static/js/bowser.js',
        './static/js/bootstrap.js',
        './static/js/jquery.resizeend.js',
        './static/js/slick.js',
        './static/js/jquery.waypoints.js',
        './static/js/jquery.backgroundpos.js',
        './static/js/jquery.fancybox.js',
        './static/js/select2.full.js',
        './static/js/jquery.mousewheel.js',
        './static/js/clipboard.js',
        './static/js/circle-progress.js',
        './static/js/common.js',
        './static/js/main.js'
    ]
},
output: {
    filename: "[name].js",
    path: "../root/js/react",
    library: '[name]'
},
```

after build all js files are minified but i have problems with these dependencies :

bootstrap can't find jquery

```
Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
    at Object.1213 (main.js:3)
    at t (main.js:1)
    at Object.0 (main.js:1)
    at t (main.js:1)
    at main.0 (main.js:1)
    at main.js:1
```

Note: Jquery comes before bootstrap so it should be ok

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Jquery comes before bootstrap so it should be ok

No that is not the case, because webpack still keeps them as modules, but bootstrap expects jQuery to be present globally. You can fix this by using the [ProvidePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/#use-jquery), so webpack automatically imports jQuery whenever it sees it being used. Add it to your `plugins` section in your webpack config:

```
plugins: [
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery'
  })
]
```

*Note: I linked the docs for webpack 2, but this works the exact same for webpack 1*.